# Cantor set and series

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Definition:** Let $\{0.a_0a_1\dotsc : a_i=0\ \text{or}\ 1\ \text{for all $i$ }\}$ be called the Cantor space.

Let $0.a_0a_1\dotso$ and $0.b_0b_1\dotso$ be members of the Cantor space.

How do I show that the series
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{|a_i-b_i|}{2^i}$$
converges?

Comment: I don't see where we need to use the definition of $x$ and $y$...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: How well do you understand decimal numbers? Can you prove that for any decimal number $.a_1a_2a_3a_4...$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{10^n}$ converges? (Of course each $a_i$ is a digit $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$).